# Checking if an image is high quality image in android before compression

Tags: android

Currently am compressing my camera images via

```
  public static String getStringImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
 }
```

The above compresses images to quality 30 and generates a base64 encoded image for upload to a php server. This works well for high resolution images, but i have an issue with already low resolution images where i would like to check if an image is a low resolution image. How can i check the bitmap passed (before compression) is a high resolution or not so as to adjust the value of quality before compression.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set a threshold for the image size. If the size is above certain threshold, you can compress and upload.